How to apply a style_edition option for rustfmt on a file saving in vscode?
I have a .vscode/settings.json file:
{
  "[rust]": {
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "offUnlessPressed",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
}

So I enjoy rs files autoformatting on save. But as I can see it runs a cargo fmt command.
I have added a style_edition = "2024" line to my rustfmt.toml. And now if I run a cargo +nightly fmt -- --check command then I get some formatting error messages.
How to force a vscode to check my rustfmt.toml file and apply a +nightly option on a formatOnSave action?

Can you please add the complete error message you get? That helps tremendously with discoverability of the question as people are likely to search for the error messages they get.

I have added an extra option rust-analyzer.rustfmt.extraArgs to my settings.json file:
{
  "[rust]": {
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "offUnlessPressed",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "rust-analyzer.rustfmt.extraArgs": ["+nightly"]
}

Now it works as I expect it - file saving applies formatting according with style_edition, imports_granularity, group_imports and other nightly options from a rustfmt.toml.
